# javascript not seeing html after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pageload, page-lifecycle

I am creating a dynamic jobs list from a database that has conditional salary reporting based on union type. To handle the conditional statements I decided to build the dataset in the in the pageload section of the cs page for output to a label on the aspx page. All works as expected. The problem comes when I try to run JQuery or Javascripts on the HTML to collapse and expand the job titles to reveal the requirements. There are tons of way to do this in using JQuery, JS and Ajaxtookit. All work like a charm on static HTML. But .Net adds a span tag to my output which throws a wrench into the layout preventing the scripts from working. I then added a JQ function to remove the span tag then run the other scripts (all which I placed at the bottom of the page so they would get called after the page was loaded). Neither Document.ready or window.load had any effect. It appears that page load and page rendered states may be the issue. How can I get JQ and JS to see the html once it's written? Thanks

CS:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String strConnString96 = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JobList_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection con96 = new OleDbConnection(strConnString96);
        OleDbCommand cmd96 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE (Status = 'Open') AND (Approved = 'Yes')", con96);
        OleDbDataAdapter da96 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd96);
        DataTable dtJobList = new DataTable();
        da96.Fill(dtJobList);
        con96.Close();

         if (dtJobList == null || dtJobList.Rows.Count == 0)
            lblJobList.Text = "<h3>No positions available at this time.</h3>";

         if (dtJobList != null && dtJobList.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

             int i = 0;
             foreach (DataRow row in dtJobList.Rows)
             {

                 string JobTitle = row["Job_Title"].ToString();
                 string Func = row["Functions"].ToString();
                 string Qual = row["Qualifications"].ToString();
                 string ReqNum = row["Req_Number"].ToString();
                 string Low = row["Low_Range"].ToString();
                 string High = row["High_Range"].ToString();
                 string SalType = row["Salary_Type"].ToString();
                 string Union = row["Union"].ToString();
                 i++;



                 sb1.Append("<div id='JobNbr-" + i + "'><h4>" + JobTitle + "</h4><h5>Essential Functions</h5><p>" + Func + "</p><h5>Qualifications</h5><p>" + Qual + "<p>");

                 if (Union == "Executive" || Union == "Local 6" || Union == "C93")
                 {

                     sb1.AppendLine("<h5>Starting Salary</h5><p>" + Low + " - " + High + " <i>(" + SalType + ")</i>");                                                                         
                 }

                 else
                 {
                     sb1.AppendLine("<h5>Starting Salary</h5><p>" + High + " <i>(" + SalType + ")</i>");

                 }

                 sb1.AppendLine("<a href='/HR_WebForm/HR_Form.aspx?Req_Number=" + ReqNum + "&Job_Title=" + JobTitle + "'><img src='/Resources/icons/apply.gif' alt='Apply' /></a></p></div>");

                 lblJobList.Text = sb1.ToString();
             }


         }
    }
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">



<h1>Employment</h1>

   <div id="Employment">
    <h2>Join New England's largest retail water &amp; sewer provider!</h2>

<h2>How to Apply:</h2>

<ol><li>Submit your resume and cover letter online, please send attachments in PDF or Microsoft Word format, if not please fax to 617-989-7754 OR</li>

<li>Visit our Human Resources Department at 980 Harrison Avenue Boston, MA 02119</li></ol>

<p>We are located on several MBTA bus routes and visitors' parking is available on-site. Our office is open Monday through Friday, 8:00AM to 5:00PM.
</p>

<p>Come join our team!</p>

<h2>Current Openings</h2>

<div id="CurrentOpenings">

    <a id="On" name="On" onclick="openAll('CurrentOpenings', 'h4','');" href="#_" class="hideIfNoJS">Open All</a>
    <a id="Off" name="Off" onclick="closeAll('CurrentOpenings', 'h4','');" href="#_" class="hideIfNoJS">Close All</a>

<asp:Label ID="lblJobList" runat="server" Text="Label" />


</div>

    <script>window.onload = "setCollapseExpand('CurrentOpenings', 'h4',''); revealControl('On'); revealControl('Off');"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JScode/expandcollapse.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting window.onload to a string.

```
window.onload = "setCollapseExpand('CurrentOpenings', 'h4',''); revealControl('On'); revealControl('Off');"</script>
```

It is expecting a function. Since you tagged this jquery, use it.

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    setCollapseExpand('CurrentOpenings', 'h4','');
    revealControl('On');
    revealControl('Off');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I am using master pages. Originally the onload was in the body tag. The same approach works on an FAQ page that is static. I've tried other expand/collapse scripts and none have worked on dynamic output they way I am doing it. I can't even get JQ to see a span tag. If it weren't for the conditional output I'd use a listview. Tried handling it that way with inline code but was unable to get eval expression to work within an inline code block. I've set clientID to static but that doesn't prevent the span tag from attaching itself to my code. Ugh!

Comment: I found a solution. According to the .Net documentation, dynamically generated content does not necessarily strictly adhere to page life-cycle allowing for some lapse in timing. When I added a new content placeholder below the body tag, this added enough delay for my table to render before the JS was called. Simply placing the JS code as the last element before the closing body tag didn't cut it. It seems that each placeholder renders completely before moving on to the next one. Acting like a period at the end of a sentence, that little pause was all it took.

Comment: Unless the content is being loaded by Ajax, the code should be there onload.